# open source ranking algorithms used by Solr

Tags: solr

I am working on Solr. I want to know what ranking algorithm it uses when output a query.  I am also using Solr search.

Answer (score 3):

Solr uses the [Lucene Core](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) , a text search library written in Java, for text search. This is the same project that also powers Elasticsearch, so everything here applies to Elasticsearch too.

The core ranking algorithm (also known as the similarity algorithm) is based on Term-Frequency/Inverse-Document-Frequency, or [tf/idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) for short . td/idf takes the following factors into account:

(I've copied in a description of tf/idf below from the Elasticsearch documentation - the description would be identical for Solr but this is much better written and easier to understand)

> **Term frequency**
>
> How often does the term appear in the field? The more often, the more
>   relevant. A field containing five mentions of the same term is more
>   likely to be relevant than a field containing just one mention.
>
> **Inverse document frequency**
>
> How often does each term appear in the index? The more often, the less
>   relevant. Terms that appear in many documents have a lower weight than
>   more uncommon terms.
>
> **Field norm**
>
> How long is the field? The longer it is, the less likely it is that
>   words in the field will be relevant. A term appearing in a short title
>   field carries more weight than the same term appearing in a long
>   content field.

You can find the specifics of the Lucene similarity scoring here: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

Keep in mind that Solr/Lucene supports a rich set of functionality to alter this scoring. This is best read about [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring) in the discussion on Lucene scoring.

If you want to read more about scoring and how to change it I'd start here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

And then I would read up a bit on what a Function Query is:

> FunctionQuery allows one to use the actual value of a field and
>   functions of those fields in a relevancy score.

Basically it provides you with a relatively easy to use mechanism to adjust the relevancy score of a document as a function of the values within certain fields:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery

Comment: how can I change scoring

Comment: How to use above factors in order to change scoring according to my need

Comment: I think how can I change scoring is too broad to address in a single answer. I'd start looking here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ and then read about FunctionQueries: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery